# Why would replacing a div via a GET request through AJAX cause my website to slow down so much compared to no JavaScript at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, get

So the whole reason I am using AJAX is to make page changes seem smoother. However I have realized that using AJAX is actually slowing down the website significantly. I am using localhost with apache. I am running php on the backend to access a database for various pages.

It's taken up to 5 seconds just to load a single page.

Here is some AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu_nav").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "menu.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                var toInsert = $(data).filter(".placeholder");
                var style = $(data).filter("#style");
                $("#style").replaceWith(style);
                $(".placeholder").replaceWith(toInsert);
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

'menu_nav' and 'home_nav' are both divs with click events attached to them, and on click they are performing a GET request to the server and asking for a div in the .php as well as it's styling sheet. It then will replace the div and style sheet on this page with what it retrieved from the GET request. Where I am having trouble understanding though is why is this taking up to 5 seconds to perform the GET request, whereas without any javascript I am getting minuscule load times, just less "pretty"?

I looked at the timeline and network tabs in the web inspector, and had noticed that every time I perform one of these requests, I get a new file from the server, rather than reading the one I've already got, which makes sense because there might be new data in the page since the last visit, however I don't see a duplicate being added to the list of sources when I am not using AJAX. For example:
[image: Multiple files in sources]

Whereas without AJAX, there is only one. This makes sense since I am initiating a GET request to the server, but the same is happening when you click a link without AJAX.

Regardless, I still don't understand what is making it so slow as opposed to not using JavaScript. I understand it is doing more in addition to just a GET request, but is filtering and replacing text after a response really what is causing this issue?

Side question: This is outside the scope of this question, but in regards to AJAX, when I perform a request to the server, is the PHP within the file still executing before it gives me the HTML? So on pages where a user must have certain permissions, will the PHP that catches that still be ran?

EDIT: I am hosting a MySQL database through a free subscription to a cloud hosting service. This issue occurs when I access my website through both localhost, and when accessing the website that way deployed via the free cloud hosting service, though it is way slower when I use the cloud service. I am also using various resources from the MAMP (MacOS Apache, MySQL, PHP; If you're on windows and interested, WAMP is also available fore free) installation.

Comment: Looks like a database issue

Comment: @quantumPuter I believe you're right.

Comment: I've noticed someone has downvoted my question! I understand that my question may be flawed. I would appreciate it if you/someone could let me know how my question can be improved! I have been getting some downvotes recently and I'd like to figure out what I can do better!

Comment: You posted a lot of code with a log of tags.  That means a lot of people might have to look at your code only to discover there is no reward for you or them.  Try to pinpoint the issue better.

Comment: @quantumPuter makes sense, thank you. I am going to try to shorten it up for future readers.

Comment: Additional information request from your hosting service. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 of your slow tests processed UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing your slowness issues, but you could try doing some profiling to narrow down the issue. My guess is that while changing your code to use ajax, you also introduced or revealed some bug that's causing this slowness issue.

- Is there an issue with the javascript? You can place [console.time()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) and [console.timeEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd) in different places to see how long a chunk of javascript takes to execute. (e.g. at the start and end of your ajax callback). Based on what you posted, this is likely not the issue, but you can always double check.
- Is it PHP that's running slow? You can use similar profiling functions in PHP to make sure it's not hanging on something.
- Are there network issues? You could, for example, log the timestamp of when javascript sent the request and when PHP received it, and vice versa. (this should work OK on localhost, but in other environments you have to be careful of clocks being out of sync)

There's a lot that could be going wrong here, so its hard to give a more specific answer, but hopefully that gives you some tools to help you start looking.

As for your side question: you are correct - PHP will start sending the HTML while it continues to execute. For example:

```
<div>
  <?php someLongBlockingFunction(); ?>
</div>
```

`<div>` will get sent to the browser, then PHP will stall on the long-running-function before it finally sends out the ending `</div>`. The browser will piece together the chunks, and your event listener won't get called until PHP has finished sending the entire file.

Comment: I think it has to do with databases and images! I've got a follow up question for you if you've got the time  and don't mind helping, because you seem knowledgable. If I am hosting a MySQL database through an unpaid third party like Heroku or AWS, can I expect query results to get to me faster when I eventually host the website publicly through a more costlier subscription? I was doing like you said, and logged the time all over the place, and found that it was database access that is doing it. So I'm not going to overcompensate on load delays if it's gonna get better when I upgrade.

Comment: Glad you were able to narrow down the issue! I'm not actually all that knowledgeable in this area :p - but yes, I would assume when you move to a paid subscription, your database queries would run faster.

I still am a bit surprised that the queries are running that slow - but I don't know how much you're being throttled on the free plan. There could be other problems at play too e.g. are you doing lots of blocking queries in series, instead of async, or, are you doing huge queries like downloading an entire table, when you could use smaller ones.

Comment: @backwardforward Second request, additional information request from your hosting service. RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 4 of your slow tests processed UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.